# Split and join in JavaScript?

Tags: javascript, replace, split

I have a String "SHELF-2-1-1-2-1", I need to remove "2" from that string and want the output to be "SHELF-1-1-2-1"

I tried:

```
var str = "SHELF-2-1-1-2-1";
var res = str.split("-");
```

How can I join the array to get "SHELF-1-1-2-1"?

Comment: Do you want to remove the character `2`, or whatever character is in the 7th position? Will it always be a single character that is being removed, or will it sometimes be more than one character?

Comment: Why not just `str.replace("-2","")`?

Comment: Please read [how to ask a good question](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask). This question attracted a lot of answers before it was clarified, and even now there are multiple ways to interpret what is being asked, and unspecified requirements.

Answer (score 14):

This would work:

```
var str = "SHELF-2-1-1".split('-2').join('');
```

Comment: Wow, that's a smart answer! I was trying to solve it based on the code user3271040 put in his question, but yours circumvents that and is really simple. I'll remember that kind of approach!!

Comment: what if in this case, "SHELF-2-1-1-2" it gives as "SHELF-1-1", while it should be "SHELF-1-1-2"

Answer (score 9):

Sounds like you want to do a replace... Try:

`var res = str.replace('-2', '');`

Comment: This is the cleanest answer IMO

Comment: It turns "SHELF-2-10-20" into "SHELF-100" which may not be wanted. And it's possible that only the first instance is supposed to be replaced. The question is quite unclear.

Comment: No, it turns `"SHELF-2-10-20"` into `"SHELF-10-20"`. By default. [replace](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/replace) only replaces the first occurrence. To perform a global replace, the first parameter needs to be a regular expression with the `g` flag applied.

Answer (score 4):

```
var str = "SHELF-2-1-1";
var res = str.split("-");
res.pop(res.indexOf('2'));
var newStr = res.join('-');
```

This should also work for your updated question, as it will only remove the first `2` from the string

Answer (score -2):

```
 let str = "Hello India";

 let split_str = str.split("");
 console.log(split_str);

 let join_arr = split_str.join("");
 console.log(join_arr);
```